# Using INDEX MATCH across multiple sheets with a named range

Tags: excel-formula

On Sheet A, I have the named range salaries2010. My goal is to reference a value from that range on Sheet B.

On Sheet A, this formula returns the correct value:

```
=INDEX(salaries2010,6,MATCH(C518,INDEX(salaries2010,1,0),0))
```

I know Sheet B able to reference the named range salaries2010 because this formula, in which I just point to the cell without using MATCH, returns the correct value:

```
=INDEX(salaries2010,6,1)
```

Alas, on Sheet B, my original formula doesn't work, even after I change the search term to C51 (where the same term resides)

```
=INDEX(salaries2010,6,MATCH(C51,INDEX(salaries2010,1,0),0))
```

I get the #NA! error.

Any ideas on what's wrong? Some idiosyncrasy of looking things up between sheets?

Comment: `#N/A` means the match was not found.  `#REF` would indicate that the reference was bad.  Check the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can also Evaluate the formula(Formulas => evaluate formula on ribbon), and check where the N/A result returns.